# AND filter elastic search PHP

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm trying to have multiple queries in `ELASTIC SEARCH` However I just want to have an operator `AND` to separate them as condition, for example as in SQL,

```
SELECT * FROM table where P=1 AND Q=2
```

In such query, we find only those results which will fulfil both conditions. In my case, P=1 is my first query and Q=2 is my second one.

How can I get the results for such query. Im using PHP.
Here's my Code:

```
// MY QUERY 1
$query["bool"]["must"][]["multi_match"] = array(
            "query"=>$string,
            "operator" => "and",
            "fields" => array("firstname", "lastname")
            );

// MY QUERY 2

$query["bool"]["must"][]["multi_match"] = array(
                 'query'  =>$string2,
                 'fields' => array("firstname1", "firstname2")
            );
// SEARCH

$return = $client->search(
                array(
                    'index' => 'my_index',
                    'type'  =>  'typ',
                    'body'  => array(
                        'query' => $query,
                        'size' => 100,
                    ),
                )
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter query with an and operator like this. Try it out.

```
{
  "filter": {
    "and": [
      {
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "searchTerm1",
                  "fields": [
                    "firstname",
                    "lastname"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "searchTerm2",
                  "fields": [
                    "firstname1",
                    "firstname2"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```